# Pig ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias test

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I get:

```
org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for test
```

when I have the code:

```
my_file = LOAD '$my_records_file' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (field0:chararray, field1:int);
test = FILTER my_file BY field0 != null;
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to filter rows that have null values ?
the Syntax is field0 IS NOT NULL.

```
my_file = LOAD '$my_records_file' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (field0:chararray, field1:int);
test = FILTER my_file BY field0 IS NOT NULL;
```

but if you want to filter rows that have a value equals to null, the code is :

```
my_file = LOAD '$my_records_file' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (field0:chararray, field1:int);
test = FILTER my_file BY field0 !='null';
```

Comment: Yes, I wanted to filter rows that have null values. Thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

One of the other reasons to get this error is that running Pig through local Mode or HDFS mode. Apart from this error there is a message on our console, **failed to read data from the path**. If this is the case then **check first you are working with Pig in Local mode or HDFS mode**. In local mode PIG will take input data from LFS (Local file system). However, in HDFS it will take input data from the HDFS directory.

> Backend error message during job submission org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist:
>
> Pig Stack Trace: ERROR 1066:  Unable to open iterator for alias

So, be sure while loading the file to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
my_file = LOAD '$my_records_file' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (field0:chararray, field1:int);
test = FILTER my_file BY field0 != null;
```

has an error.

`field0 != null` should be `field0 != 'null'`.

This code:

```
my_file = LOAD '$my_records_file' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (field0:chararray, field1:int);
test = FILTER my_file BY field0 != 'null';
```

corrects the error.